# the length of a perpendicular inside of a triangle

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ a triangle with its area $S$ and $AB=c$, $BC=a$, $AC=b$.
The median from $A$ intersects the bisecting of the angle $ABC$ in $X$.
If $x=\ $the length of the perpendicular from $X$ on $BC$ than $x$ is:

A: $2S/(a+b+c)$

B: $2S/(2c+a)$

C: $(c+a)/2$

D: $(2c+a)/3$

E: $2S/(2b+a)$

I made a sketch and used the bisecting theorem and get that $AX/XM=2c/a$ and from the median theorem I got the length of $AX$ and $XM$.
With the Pythagoras theorem if I find $QM$ ($Q$ being the projection of $X$ on $BC$) I could find $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there: if $H$ is the perpendicular projection from $A$ on $BC$ and $Q$ is the perpendicular projection from $X$ on $BC$ ($XQ=x$), then:
$$
AH/XQ=AM/XM=1+AX/XM
\quad\text{and}\quad
AH=2S/a.
$$